# Member of static member

Tags: c++, oop, static, member

How do I access a member of a static member of other class?

Like so:

code.hpp:

```
class A
{
public:
    int* member;
    A();
};

class B
{
public:
    static A* StatOBJ;
};
```

code.cpp:

```
A* B::StatOBJ = new A();
int* B::StatOBJ->member = 42                //ERROR
```

I would prefer to have this outside of main()  (or any other function - just like static variables are defined) but I tried it inside main() as well.

A() puts some value to member (and therefore initializes it) and I want to change it.

When I try to compile this I get:

error: expected initializer before '->' token

on the line with //ERROR

Comment: "member" is scoped as private by default.  So you cannot access it.

Comment: Try something insane: `A* B::StatObj = (B::StatObj = new A, B::StatObj->member = 42, B::StatObj);`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put public there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A::member` is not declared as `static`, so do not specify its data type again when assigning its value:

```
B::StatObJ->member = ...;
```

Also, `A::member` is declared as a pointer, so you have to allocate it before you can assign a value to it:

```
B::StatObJ->member = new int;
*(B::StatObJ->member) = 42;
```

Or:

```
B::StatObJ->member = new int(42);
```

Either way, both of those would be better served by giving `A` a constructor to handle that allocation/assignment:

```
class A
{
public:
    int* member;
    A();
    ~A();
};
```

```
A::A()

    : member(new int(42))
{
}

A::~A()
{
    delete member;
}
```

```
A* B::StatObJ = new A();
```

Or better:

```
class A
{
public:
    int* member;
    A(int value);
    ~A();
};
```

```
A::A(int value)
    : member(new int(value))
{
}

A::~A()
{
    delete member;
}
```

```
A* B::StatObJ = new A(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some minor modifications to your code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public: //needs to be public
     int* member;
};

class B
{
    public: // needs to be public
    static A* StatOBJ;
};
A* B::StatOBJ; //needs to be "defined" not just "declared"



int main(){
     B::StatOBJ = new A(); // you dont want to allocate more memory so drop the type
     B::StatOBJ->member = new int(42);   // unless you change A::member to int instead of (*int) this must be done  
}
```